# Excel Range object throws error 0x800A03EC because of a string longer than 255 characters

Tags: matlab, excel, vba

Using an ActiveX server from MATLAB, I am trying to highlight many cells in an Excel sheet at once. These are not in specific columns or rows so I use `Range('A1,B2,...')` to access them. However the string accepted by the Range object has to be less than 255 characters or an error:

> Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC

is thrown. The following code reproduces this error with an empty Excel file.

```matlab
hActX = actxserver('Excel.Application');
hWB = hActX.Workbooks.Open('C:\Book1.xlsx');
hSheet = hWB.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1');

col = repmat('A', 100, 1);
row = num2str((1:100)'); %'
cellInd = strcat(col, strtrim(cellstr(row)));
str1 = strjoin(cellInd(1:66), ','); %// 254 characters
str2 = strjoin(cellInd(1:67), ','); %// 258 characters

hSheet.Range(str1).Interior.Color = 255; %// Works
hSheet.Range(str2).Interior.Color = 255; %// Error 0x800A03EC

hWB.Save;
hWB.Close(false);
hActX.Quit;
```

How can I get around this? I found no other relevant method of calling Range, or of otherwise getting the cells I want to modify.

Comment: Would it be possible to you to call a formatting macro on the Excel spredsheet?

Comment: I corrected the syntax highlighting in your question but it looks like you've got a rouge apostrophe in there...

Comment: You have to use the excel application's `Union` method to join multiple ranges.

Comment: @MacroMan I fixed the formatting

Comment: @Rory Using `Union` works! I'm not sure yet how to generalize this to strings of any length, though.

Comment: Don't build up the string at all - just union every range.

Comment: I can't do a single union for all cells as `Union` takes a maximum of 30 arguments. So this means iterating over all cells and adding them to the union. I'm not sure this is preferable to just iterating over all cells and modifying their properties (which is what I do now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as Rory pointed out, is to use the [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) method. To minimize the number of calls from MATLAB to the ActiveX server, this is what I did:

```
str = strjoin(cellInd, ',');
isep = find(str == ',');
isplit = diff(mod(isep, 250)) < 0;
isplit = [isep(isplit) (length(str) + 1)];
hRange = hSheet.Range(str(1:(isplit(1) - 1)));
for ii = 2:numel(isplit)
    hRange = hActX.Union(hRange, ...
                 hSheet.Range(str((isplit(ii-1) + 1):(isplit(ii) - 1))));
end
```

I used `250` in the `mod` to account for the cell names being up to 6 characters long, which is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a `String`, you can test its length to determine if `Range()` can handle it.  Here is an example of building a diagonal range:

```
Sub DiagonalRange()
    Dim BigString As String, BigRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, HowMany As Long, Ln As String

    HowMany = 100

    For i = 1 To HowMany
        BigString = BigString & "," & Cells(i, i).Address(0, 0)
    Next i
    BigString = Mid(BigString, 2)
    Ln = Len(BigString)
    MsgBox Ln

    If Ln < 250 Then
        Set BigRange = Range(BigString)
    Else
        Set BigRange = Nothing
        arr = Split(BigString, ",")
        For Each a In arr
            If BigRange Is Nothing Then
                Set BigRange = Range(a)
            Else
                Set BigRange = Union(BigRange, Range(a))
            End If
        Next a
    End If

    BigRange.Select
End Sub
```

For `i = 10`, the code will the the direct method, but if the code were `i=100`, the array method would be used.

Comment: I'm working in MATLAB, invoking Excel's interface via an ActiveX server. This is similar to what I did now following Rory's suggestions.